# Trouble assigning data in a cell to a variable

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I am writing code that takes data from one excel document and puts it into another. My idea on doing this would be to write the data from the starting workbook to a variable, and then using that variable write the data to the end workbook. Here is my code:

```
sApp = new Excel.Application
sApp.Visible = false;
sBook = sApp.Workbooks.Open(SfilePath.ToString());
sSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sBook.Sheets[1];
```

That is just the intro code to get into the workbook, here is the code I am having problems with:

```
formNumber = (string)(sSheet.Cells["J2"] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
```

When I run my program, I get an error that says

> ArgumentException was unhandled. 
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

When I researched this error code (HRESULT: 0x80070057) I found others had the same problem. However all the solutions given have not worked for me (i.e. clear out the bin, clear out the Temp Files).

Is there any insight anyone can give me? If you think you might need to know a bit more about the code let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: @findwindow So I wouldn't include the end **" ; "** then? I am writing this code in visual studio with visual C# so I figured I would follow standard C# rules.

Comment: maybe i got it wrong, but is there nothing between `(string)` and `(sSheet.Ce...`? like `,` or `&`... just a question...

Comment: @DirkReichel correct there is nothing in between there. I have it this way because in my research to solve this problem, someone mentioned this is a good way to go about setting up that specific bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, I was trying to call up the cells by their name "J2" , "K2".
But you cannot do that, it has to be by their point location. Thanks for everyone that submitted answers, I appreciate it.

Comment: You can use "J2", "K2" but just in Range. string formNumber = sSheet.Range["J2"].Text.ToString();

Comment: Find my below answer for detailed code

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Excel.Range workSheetUsedRange = sSheet.UsedRange;
    
string formNumber = string.Empty;
    
if ((workSheetUsedRange.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
{
    formNumber = (workSheetUsedRange.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
}
excelUtil.SaveWorkBook(file, ref workbook);
```

You can use this code to get the value of any cell using rowIndex and columnIndex.
It is a good practise to check if the value of the cell that you are trying to read is null. If the value is null, you get an exception.

Comment: Alright, So i put this into my code, and im looking through it and im having some questions. What is the purpose of the last line in there. Also i ran the code without the last line and im still getting the 0x80070057 Error, except this time its pointing to the end of the if ((workSheetUsedRange.Cells.... portion

Answer (score 0):

It's simple,
If you use String address value with Cell["J2"] then it'll throw invalid parameter error.

Only thing you need to change is replace Cell with Range, then it'll work without any issues.

```
string formNumber = sSheet.Range["J2"].Text.ToString();
```

Or if you only want to use Cell for some reason, then use this way,

```
// Note J = 10
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
string formNumber = (sSheet.Cells[10, 2] as xl.Range).Text.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Last line is to save the workbook. Looks like I pasted a code using my utility library. You can use the code for save instead. Along with the error code you have mentioned, what is the error message that you receive? Could you provide additional details that could help in understanding the problem/error?

Comment: Here is a picture of the full error message box that appears: http://i.imgur.com/DtTGHG0.png  This is with the updated code (the error box is pointing to the last parentheses on the if statement line.